# How to get the array size without null element in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, size

I am new learner to C++.
I announce a string array which has null value inside, and I want to get the array size of the array.

However, I can only get the size with null value.
How can I get the size without null value?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string arr[100] = {"a","b","c"};
  int len = end(arr) - begin(arr);
  cout << len;
  //I do not want the count the null element.
  //I want to cout len = 3
}
```

Thank you for answering.

[image]

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string> arr = {"a","b","c"};` and the `size()` function.

Comment: What is the null value of std::string?

Comment: The strings in your array are better described as empty than null. Null has a specific meaning to do with pointers that could be confusing in this context.

Comment: *I am new learner to C++.*  New learners to C++ should use `std::vector` rather than the advanced topic of C-style arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to count the number of elements in the array `arr` before the element containing empty string that is before the so-called sentinel value.

In this case you need to use a loop sequentially checking each element of the array. Such a loop is hidden in the standard algorithm `std::find`.

For example you can write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string arr[100] = { "a","b","c" };

    auto last = std::find( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ), "" );

    auto count = std::distance( std::begin( arr ), last );

    std::cout << count  << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

Pay attention to that in general if your program deals with objects of the type `std::string`  then you need explicitly to include the header `<string>`.